# How do I import catboost_spark in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: amazon-ec2, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, catboost

currently trying to import catboost_spark following the directions on catboost.ai -

i am trying to run it in a jupyter notebook on Amazon EMR, but it keeps giving me a ModuleNotFoundError.

any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to SO, you will most likely get a faster response if you share the fraction of the code where you import the module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add spark config via magic `%%configure` with the needed `jar` package before obtaining the `SparkSession`:

```
%%configure
{
    "conf": { "spark.jars.packages": "ai.catboost:catboost-spark_3.3_2.13:1.1.1" }
}
```

Then you can call to the `%%spark` magic to obtain the pre-defined `spark` object, which refers the `SparkSession`:

```
%%spark
```

You will se the following message:

```
Starting Spark application
ID  YARN Application ID             Kind    State   Spark UI    Driver log  User    Current session?
5   application_1677583254118_0006  pyspark idle    Link        Link        None    ✔
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

Then you can import the needed module `catboost_spark`:

```
import catboost_spark
```

And it would be imported successfully